# R studio Rolling returns

Tags: r

I have quarterly stock returns data and would like to calculate rolling annual returns. For example:

The Rolling_Annual Return for q4_2000 is = (1+0.042) * (1-0.1814) * (1+0.0353) * (1-0.0143)-1 = -12.95%

```
Date_2   Stock     Rolling_Annual Returns
Q1_2000     4.20%
Q2_2000   -18.14%
Q3_2000     3.53%
Q4_2000    -1.43%        -12.95%
Q1_2001    -0.65%        -17.00% 
Q2_2001     1.90%          3.31%
Q3_2001     3.68%          3.46%
Q3_2001    -0.49%          4.44%
Q4_2001    11.37%         17.08%
```

I'm not sure the best way to approach this in R? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rollapplyr` from `zoo` to calculate the rolling calculation.

```
zoo::rollapplyr(df$Stock/100, 4, function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1, fill = NA) * 100
#[1]     NA    NA    NA -12.9537 -17.0053   3.3125   3.4622   4.4489  17.0858
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date_2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 8L), .Label = c("Q1_2000", "Q1_2001", "Q2_2000", "Q2_2001", 
"Q3_2000", "Q3_2001", "Q4_2000", "Q4_2001"), class = "factor"), 
Stock = c(4.2, -18.14, 3.53, -1.43, -0.65, 1.9, 3.68, -0.49, 
11.37)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you @ Ronak Shah! This is very helpful. One more question (sorry), if I want it as a column/new variable within the same DF what is the best way?

Comment: Perhaps  `transform(DF, roll = 100 * (rollapplyr(1+Stock/100, 4, prod, fill = NA) - 1))`

Comment: @CISCO Do you mean to assign value to new column? `df$Rolling_Annual <- zoo::rollapplyr(df$Stock/100, 4, function(x) .....`

Comment: @RonakShah Yep! Sorry for such a basic question. Greatly appreciated.